# Load the new data on click of different anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]As I am new to this concepts, please dont mind if there are any mistakes. I need help.
Here all the anchor tags are hard coded, but actually they should be created dynamically.
I am trying to display the data on click of anchor tag..
the data to be displayed is different in this scenario.
Initially we are showing devices such as SmartPhone and Tablet.
On Click of smartphone we have to display os versions such as mac,windows,andriod and blackberry which is completely related to smartphone... same on click of tablet also these 4 os versions will be displayed related to tablet.
again onclick of os versions link then based on that os, the versions of os should be displayed.
For eg: 4.0 ics,4.1:jellybean and etc.., 
This OS data should be displayed only when Smartphone/ Tablet is selected..
Here is the code what I have tried...!
html:

```
    <table id="layout">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <table id='download'>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div id='main'>
    <table id='device'>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <a id='mobile_select'> SmartPhone </a>
    <div id="os_data">
    <a >ios</a>
    <a >andriod</a>
    <a >blackberry</a>
    <a >windows</a></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <a> Tablet</a>
 <div id="os_data">
    <a >ios</a>
    <a >andriod</a>
    <a >blackberry</a>
    <a >windows</a></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Jquery

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
         $('#device').append('<a  + i + > ' + i + '</a>');
     }

     addOS();

     function addOS() {
            ii = 0;

            for (i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
                if ((i % 10) == 0) {
                    ii++;
                }
                $('#device').append('<a + i +  id="oos' + ii + '"> ' + i + '</a>');
            }
        }

     $('#mobile_select').click(function() {
            var selectedDevice = $(this).val();
            var selectFirst = 0;
            addCites();

            $("#device").each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr('id') != selectedDevice) {
                    $(this).remove();
                } else {
                    if (selectFirst < 1) {
                        $(this).attr('id', selectedDevice).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    }
                    selectFirst++;
                }
            });
            $("#device").parent().parent().show();


        });
```

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. They're painful and haven't been needed since CSS support in browsers became decent (i.e. for well over a decade).

Comment: @Quentin : Thanks, i wont use from now onwards, could you please help me out on my posted question.

Comment: I cannot understand this statement "This OS data should be displayed only when Smartphone/ Tablet is selected.." Please clear this so that I can help you.

Comment: @HarryBomrah : hai I added screenshot for better understanding.

Comment: @HarryBomrah : Hai harry have u understand the concept. I attached a screenshot.

Comment: @user1853128, How is your data stored? I see no data in question. When user clicks on tablet, where is the OS data of tablets?

Comment: @SadullahCeran : Hi, I added for tablet also, but it should generate dynamically because there mignt be n number of OS data

Comment: So as far as I understand. you get OS when you click smartphone or tab. and when you click os, you should get os versions. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not use tables for layout.
Here is what you need to do to achieve your task.

HTML:

```
<div id="mainCategories">
    <a id="smartPhone" href="">SmartPhones</a>
    <a id="tablet" href="">Tablets</a>
</div>
<div id="subCategories">
</div>
```

Javascript (with jQuery):

```
$(function() {

    var data = {};
    data["smartPhone"] = ["ios", "android", "windows"];
    data["tablet"] = ["iosTablet", "androidTabled", "windowsTablet"];

    $("#mainCategories a").click(function(){
        var clickedItem = $(this).attr('id');
        var operatingSystems = data[clickedItem];
        $("#subCategories").empty();
        for(ind in operatingSystems){
            var os = operatingSystems[ind];
            var anchor = $("<a>");
            anchor.attr('href','');
            anchor.attr('id', os);
            anchor.text(os);
            $("#subCategories").append(anchor);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
a{
    display:block;
}
```

Here is working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/t426J/

Assuming you have loaded your data regarding to operating systems into javascript somehow.